# How To Save Imagemagick Conversion

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, imagemagick, imagick

In my web app I'm currently using digibook to convert pdfs to a image file however the quality of the conversion are horrible. Digibook is using imagemagick but it was just a plug and play way for me to setup what I want and I really don't know how to modify it to improve quality.

I've been searching around and found the code below on stackoverflow which I use to load my PDF dynamically on a page. The problem rendering the PDF page like this is page load time suffers. How can I save each page of the PDF using the code below. I'm going to need a way to save each page of the PDF like page-0.jpg

I have a function called pdfPages($filepath) that can be used to get the pages.

```
if($file_type == ".pdf") 
            {
                if (!isset($page) && $page == "") { $page = "0"; } 
                $im = new imagick(''.$file_location.'['.$page.']');
                $im->setCompressionQuality(97);
                $im->setImageFormat('png');
                header('Content-Type: image/png');
                echo $im;

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use `writeImage()` function?

You can use it like:

```
$image->writeImage($your_file);
```

For more information [refer here](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.writeimage.php)